# Find the repeating string in the txt file and modifiy with samename_modified format

Tags: regex, string, tcl

Please help: my txt file contains these kind of data.
I need to find the repeating string and if the string repeating then modify the post_suffix with:

```
a
b
st1
ver1
st2
ver2
st3
st4
st_list1
ver3
ver4
ver_list1
st1
ver5
st2
ver5
st1
ver6
```

Oitput file should be like this:

```
a
b
st1
ver1
st2
ver2
st3
st4
st_list1
ver3
ver4
ver_list1
st1_repeted1
ver5
st2_repeted1
ver5_repeted1
st1_repeted2
ver6
```

My code:

```
if {$rec == "st1"} {
#st1 
incr count_set1 
if {$count_set1 == 1} {
    #puts $fd "$new"
    } else {
        set pr_st1 $rec$U$count_set1
        regsub $rec $content $pr_st1 new_set 
        puts $fd "$new_set"
    } 
}
```

Comment: actually i'm trying by searching the exact string but i'm not getting how to generalize the code .and confused with loop

Comment: if {$rec == "st1"} {
    #st1 
     incr count_set1 
     if {$count_set1 == 1} {
      #puts $fd "$new"
      } else {
      set pr_st1 $rec$U$count_set1
      regsub $rec $content $pr_st1 new_set 
       puts $fd "$new_set"
       } 
     }

Comment: @Punith Is Perl ok with you?

Comment: @Punith Put that in your question please. I can't read it properly that way...

Comment: @jkshah if it would be TCL that would be great .

Comment: @Jerry is it ok now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how your code exactly should work and it seems it will check only for `st1`

I would use something like this:

```
set file [open "File.txt" r]
set output [open "output.txt" w]

set wordlist ""

while {[gets $file line] != -1} {
    set id [lsearch -regexp $wordlist "^$line \[0-9]+$"]
    if {$id == -1} {
        lappend wordlist "$line 0"
        puts $output $line
        puts "new"
    } else {
        set count [lindex [lindex $wordlist $id] 1]
        incr count
        puts $output "${line}_repeated$count"
        set wordlist [lreplace $wordlist $id $id "$line $count"]
        puts repeated
    }
}

close $file
close $output
```

This allows you to check for any lines. If you have large files though, the processing time will shoot up.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this would be

```
set file [lindex $argv 0]
set f_in [open $file r]
set new ${file}.new
set f_out [open $new w]

array set count {}

while {[gets $f_in line] != -1} {
    if {[info exists count($line)]} {
        set line [format "%s_repeated%d" $line $count($line)]
    }
    puts $f_out $line
    incr count($line)
}

close $f_in
close $f_out

# backup the original file and move the new file into place
file link -hard $file ${file}.old
file rename -force $new $file
```